# How to handle a multivariable class object returning from a static function

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

I am not sure how to handle a multivariable class object returning from a static function.

You can not use a `foreach` statement with an object.

How do I get an array of class objects back from a static function?

*Default.aspx.cs*

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = TextBox1.Text;
    object returnedData = Getdata(ID);
    ????

}
public static object Getdata(string ID)
{
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    List<dataclass> returndata = new List<dataclass>();
    dataclass dc = new dataclass();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
    string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", ID);
                SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (myReader.Read())
                {
                    dc.idd = Convert.ToString(myReader["idd"]);
                    dc.datetime = Convert.ToString(myReader["datetime"]);
                    dc.col1 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col1"]);
                    dc.col2 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col2"]);
                    dc.col3 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col3"]);
                    returndata.Add(dc);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return returndata;
}
```

*Class1.cs*

```
public class dataclass
{
    public string idd { get; set; }
    public string datetime { get; set; }
    public string col1 { get; set; }
    public string col2 { get; set; }
    public string col3 { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Just return `List<dataclass>` from the method.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = TextBox1.Text;
    List<dataclass> returnedData = Getdata(ID);
    foreach (var dc in returnedData)
    {
        // Do something with dc.idd, dc.datetime, dc.col1, dc.col2, dc.col3
    }

}

public static List<dataclass> Getdata(string ID)
{
    List<dataclass> returndata = new List<dataclass>();
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
    string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", ID);
            using (SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (myReader.Read())
                {
                    dataclass dc = new dataclass();
                    dc.idd = Convert.ToString(myReader["idd"]);
                    dc.datetime = Convert.ToString(myReader["datetime"]);
                    dc.col1 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col1"]);
                    dc.col2 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col2"]);
                    dc.col3 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col3"]);
                    returndata.Add(dc);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returndata;
}
```

A couple of notes:

1. You didn't need the `DataSet` or `DataTable`. Notice that you weren't using them.
2. Don't use try/catch blocks unless you need to. You would have been hiding exceptions from yourself, which makes it hard to fix them.
3. Your `SqlDataReader` also needed a `using` block.
4. You should create a new `dc` each time through the loop. Your code would have created a single instance of `dataclass`, then created a list of `n` different references to that same instance. You would have been overwriting the contents of that one instance.

---

### EDIT:

Assuming that the `[idd]` column is the primary key of the table, then there will always be either one row returned, or else zero. In this case, you don't need the loop, and you don't need to return a list.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ID = TextBox1.Text;
    dataclass dc = Getdata(ID);
    if (dc != null)
    {
        // Do something with dc.idd, dc.datetime, dc.col1, dc.col2, dc.col3
    }
}

public static dataclass Getdata(string ID)
{
    string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["jsonobject"].ConnectionString;
    string cmdStr = "SELECT ([idd],[datetime],[col1],[col2],[col3]) FROM [jsondata] WHERE [idd]=@idd;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdStr, conn))
        {
            conn.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idd", ID);
            using (SqlDataReader myReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (myReader.Read())
                {
                    dataclass dc = new dataclass();
                    dc.idd = Convert.ToString(myReader["idd"]);
                    dc.datetime = Convert.ToString(myReader["datetime"]);
                    dc.col1 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col1"]);
                    dc.col2 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col2"]);
                    dc.col3 = Convert.ToString(myReader["col3"]);
                    return dc;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: It still sends back nulls.  The mdf has the right data.  All the tables are right.

Comment: Check whether you are getting data back from the database. Use a breakpoint and debug.

Comment: Then you've got a different problem. Try executing the query in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) and see what gets returned. Also, use the debugger to set a breakpoint and verify that ID has the value you expect. Also, what is the data type of the `idd` column?

Comment: Is there any way to convert returnedData to dataclass dc without using foreach?

Comment: `returnedData` is already a list of `dataclass`. You need to reach inside of it. Do you believe there will never be more than one `dataclass` instance inside of `returnedData`? If so, then the method can be simplified.